# Does AbsoluteTiming slow the evaluation time?

Tags: programming, evaluation

I've started using `AbsoluteTiming` to discriminate between similar function constructs, but I sometimes feel like it takes substantially more time to evaluate a function using `AbsoluteTiming` than without.

Is this behaviour normal?

(This may qualify as a second question) Is there a way to know how much time the last evaluation took, without wrapping it in a timing function?

Comment: There used to be the package [`Utilities\`ShowTime\``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/ShowTime.html) by Roman Maeder that I used whenever I wanted the timing information to be merely printed out as opposed to being part of the output. You might want to look into it, and perhaps modify the code so that it uses `AbsoluteTiming[]` instead of `Timing[]`.

Comment: Could you show an example, where where using AbsoluteTiming to evaluate expr takes more time, the evaluating expr alone?

Comment: An example is the case of functions built using nested loops, they tend to complete faster without being wrapped in a timing function. Non-loop equivalents do not show this behaviour.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you look in the Option Inspector, there's a setting called **EvaluationCompletionAction** that I keep set to **"ShowTiming"**

[image]

The result of this is that whenever an evaluation finishes, the amount of time it took is displayed in the status area at the bottom of the notebook

[image]

This saves me from needing to remember to wrap inputs in `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming`.

One thing to note is that the time shown includes the conversion of the kernel output to boxes as well as the MathLink transmission time.  I don't think it includes any time used by the frontend to draw the result to screen.

The downside is that there's no history.

Comment: Aaah, this is interesting. I'm sure there's a way to save the time in a list. Just have to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

When I don't want to use a wrapper to see how much time is used, I use `AbsoluteTime[]`:

```
timming=AbsoluteTime[];
calculations...
timming=timming-AbsoluteTime[];
```

Something I like about `AbsoluteTime[]` is that if necessary it can be converted to "normal" time, so you can track your work.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is a noticable difference.

Considering what an easy function `AbsoluteTiming` is, you might as well build your own version and see how it compares (remember to start a fresh kernel before evaluating):

```
SetAttributes[myAbsoluteTiming, HoldAll];
myAbsoluteTiming[calculation_] := Module[{startTime, deltaTime, result},
    startTime = SessionTime[];
    result = calculation;
    deltaTime = SessionTime[] - startTime;
    {deltaTime, result}
]
myAbsoluteTiming@Prime[10^11]
```

> ```
> {7.042020, 2760727302517}
> ```

Let's compare that to the built-in function:

```
AbsoluteTiming@Prime[10^11]
```

> ```
> {7.058939, 2760727302517}
> ```

Considering how little memory and computation time is used by `myAbsoluteTiming` (just by looking at its code), I don't think there is any reason to assume that `myAbsoluteTiming` slows you down, and the intenal implementation is most likely even faster. (If you're using it a million of times in a matter of seconds, then maybe you'll notice an impact on performance, but that's hardly a useful application of the function.)

"Well, maybe `SessionTime` is slow ..." - nope:

```
AbsoluteTiming@Do[SessionTime[], {10^6}]
```

> ```
> {3.665901, Null}
> ```

Concerning your follow-up question, what you want is basically the content of the `Module` in the code for `myAbsoluteTiming` given above: determine `SessionTime` before and afterwards, calculate difference.

Comment: It's funny how in this particular example your function is faster than the built-in. :P