# How to set options in Option Inspector in notebooks by running commands?

Tags: options

It involves an order of magnitude more mouse clicks and visually searching text to set some option in the Option Inspector (which is a UX nightmare) than doing that in a notebook by running some command, or doing it in some menu or palette.  In general, how to do that by running commands?   Is there some palette for choosing and discovering configurable options?

Comment: I can confirm that the Option Inspector is indeed a total nightmare, and I'd say the same thing about *Mathematica*'s notebook options management in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All options of an any element XXX are available from your program by `Options[XXX]` or `AbsoluteOptions[XXX]`.

To change any options you can use `SetOptions[XXX, OptionName->OptionValue]`

Unfortunately not all options has clear explanation in Mathematica help system..

Comment: That's not what I meant.  I mean the configurations one is asked to set in the Options Inspector.

Comment: @qazwsx this answer is correct but incomplete (question likely to be a duplicate I would think). For global front end options replace XXX with `$FrontEnd` or `$FrontEndSession`, for notebook options use `EvaluationNotebook[]`. You can enter as many options as you want, not just one at a time. All the options set in the options inspector can be set in this way. Additionally please read docs on `CurrentValue`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, Hm, current values of an options will be obtained by Options/AbsoluteOptions isn't it? So, I guess, these data will take in account the values rewritten by FrontEnd. Or I'm wrong with this?

Comment: just for future reference, some examples of such usage can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32030/27539) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85404/27539)