# How to unset an notebook option programmatically?

Tags: front-end, options

This question is related, but not identical, to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78130/2464).

Suppose one sets a notebook option like this

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Foo->Bar];
```

...and subsequently one wants to ***unset*** this option.  Just a straightforward undoing of a previous setting, so that the setting of the option is just as it was before the `SetOptions` command above was issued.

How to do this?

One thing *not* to do is to make use of `Format > Option Inspector...`.  Avoid at all cost.  Either it's totally broken, or it is so counterintuitive that it may as well be broken.

The only solution I have found is to copy the contents of the fouled-up notebook to a fresh notebook, and overwrite the former with the latter; i.e.:

1. Ctrl+A (Edit > Select All)
2. Ctrl+C (Edit > Copy)
3. Ctrl+N (File > New)
4. Ctrl+V (Edit > Paste)
5. select original notebook
6. Ctrl+W (File > Close)
7. Ctrl+S (File > Save); overwrite original notebook by saving the notebook created in (3) to the original notebook's path

Of course, it's almost obscene to call this a "solution".

Is there some other way to return a notebook option to the setting it had when it was created?

Comment: Could you give an example of a real option you are trying to set / unset?

Comment: Also, depending on the option, it may work to set the value of the option to `Inherited`. The documentation states that, when you set a value to `Inherited`, "If no explicit setting is given at any level, then a built-in default value is used. "

Comment: @MarcoB: The option I was trying to unset was `CellContext` (which I had set to `Notebook`).  BTW, `Inherited` seems to do the trick for `CellContext` at least.  I think this would make a suitable answer, if you care to post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on my comment, and depending on the exact option whose value you are trying to unset, it may work to set the value of that option to `Inherited`.

In fact, the documentation states that when you set a value to Inherited, "If no explicit setting is given at any level, then a built-in default value is used" (from the second bullet point in the "Details" section of the [documentation page on `Inherited`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inherited.html)).

This seems to work in the OP's case for the `CellContext` option, and a few other options I tried. As another example, options such as e.g. WindowSize for the current notebook:

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> {600, 600}]
Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> Inherited]
Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]