# How to delete an option from a notebook

Tags: notebooks, options

The Q&A [How to unset an notebook option programmatically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85404/how-to-unset-an-notebook-option-programmatically) nearly asks the same question, but the focus there is on how to unset an option that has been given a value.  I just want to undo a mistake I made by setting an option that does not exist:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Foo -> Bar]
```

While the `Foo -> Bar` option does not seem to interfere with the working of the notebook or *Mathematica*, I'd like to clean up this mistake.

I'd like to keep the other notebook option settings, so copy-pasting the contents would not work exactly as I would like (a method mention in the linked Q&A). Of course I could copy the desired options, too.  I'm hoping for a more straightforward solution.

(In fact, in the actual use case, the setting was some data to be stored in `TaggingRules`.  Now the data appear twice in the notebook options, more or less; the `TaggingRules` version is the up-to-date one.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but doesn't setting a option to `Inherited` more or less do this?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit You're suggesting that I set an option `"MyData" -> Inherited` and it will be deleted?  I'll try it. -- Nope, it seems the option is kept, although the setting is now `Inherited`.

Comment: Yes, the option is still there, but I believe that the value `Inherited` more or less acts as if the option was not there in the first place.

Comment: The whole option is inert as it is, so it makes no difference what it is set to.  It's not an actual, valid notebook option.  Unknown options to notebooks seem to be ignored.  It's been there for months and I only just discovered it today.  I'd like to get rid of it, if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`NotebookGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookGet)/[`NotebookPut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookPut). Here is a function that does this:

```
RemoveNotebookOption[nbobj_, rhs_]:=With[{nb = NotebookGet[nbobj]},
    NotebookPut[
        nb /. Notebook[c_, o___] :> Notebook[c, Sequence @@ FilterRules[{o}, Except[rhs]]],
        nbobj
    ]
]
```

Let's give the evaluation notebook the option `"FOO"->"BAR"`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "FOO" -> "BAR"]
```

Check:

```
Lookup[Options[EvaluationNotebook[]], "FOO"]
```

> "BAR"

Now use `RemoveNotebookOption`:

```
RemoveNotebookOption[EvaluationNotebook[], "FOO"]
```

Check:

```
Lookup[Options[EvaluationNotebook[]], "FOO"]
```

> Missing["KeyAbsent", "FOO"]

Comment: Great! That works. Thanks. (Still wonder why there's not a direct way, why more people don't need it from time to time. Maybe doofuses like me who need to fix such blunders are few and far between.)